# Age filter in Java with ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java-stream

I want to make a method that tells me who is the oldest person in the ArrayList and who is the youngest person. The method will receive the arraylist that i want to apply the method, i have 3 in my code, each one is an contact list.

The method is suppose to return the name of the person, but i don't know how to do it. Familia, Profissional and Amigos are my arraylists and "idade" = age and "nome" = name.

```
package com.company;

public class Contato {

    public String nome;
    public int idade;
    public String sexo;
    public String profissao;
    public String telefone;
    public String email;

    public Contato(String nome, int idade, String sexo, String profissao, String telefone, String email) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.profissao = profissao;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" +
                nome + ',' +
                idade + " anos de idade, " +
                "do sexo " + sexo + ',' +
                profissao + ',' +
                " telefone nº " + telefone + ", " +
                "e-mail:" + email;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getProfissao() {
        return profissao;
    }

    public void setProfissao(String profissao) {
        this.profissao = profissao;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GestaoContatos extends Contato {

    ArrayList<Contato> Familia = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Contato> Amigos = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Contato> Profissional = new ArrayList();

    public GestaoContatos(Contato c) {
        super(c.nome, c.idade, c.sexo, c.profissao, c.telefone, c.email);
    }

    public void adicionaContato(String nomeAgenda, Contato contato) {
        if( nomeAgenda == "Familia"){
            Familia.add(contato);
        } else
            if(nomeAgenda == "Amigos"){
                Amigos.add(contato);
            } else
                if(nomeAgenda == "Profissional") {
                    Profissional.add(contato);
                } else
                    System.out.println("Indispnível");
    }

    public void eliminaContato(String nomeContato) {
        for(int i = 0; i < Familia.size(); i++) {
            if(getFamilia().contains(nomeContato)) {
                Familia.remove(nomeContato);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printaLista(String nomeAgenda){
        if(nomeAgenda.equals("Familia")) {
            Familia.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        if(nomeAgenda.equals("Amigos")) {
            Amigos.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        if(nomeAgenda.equals("Profissional")) {
            Profissional.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Opcao invalida");
        }
    }

    public void tooString() {
        var contatos = new ArrayList<Contato>();
        Familia.forEach(it -> contatos.add(it));
        Amigos.forEach(it -> contatos.add(it));
        Profissional.forEach(it -> contatos.add(it));

        System.out.println(contatos.toString());
    }

    public void olderPerson(String nomeAgenda){
        int i = 0;
        if (nomeAgenda.equals("Amigos")) {
            for (i = 0; Familia.size(); i++) {
                Familia.stream().filter();
            }

        }
    }

    public void geraListaBinaria() throws IOException {
        var file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jorge Luiz\\Desktop\\contatos.txt");
        var writer = new FileWriter(file.getName());
        writer.write(this.getProfissional().toString());
        writer.write(this.getFamilia().toString());
        writer.write(this.getProfissional().toString());
        writer.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Contato> getFamilia() {
        return Familia;
    }

    public void setFamilia(ArrayList<Contato> familia) {
        Familia = familia;
    }

    public ArrayList<Contato> getAmigos() {
        return Amigos;
    }

    public void setAmigos(ArrayList<Contato> amigos) {
        Amigos = amigos;
    }

    public ArrayList<Contato> getProfissional() {
        return Profissional;
    }

    public void setProfissional(ArrayList<Contato> profissional) {
        Profissional = profissional;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, in order to get a minimum (or maximum) value, the easiest solution is to pick an impossibly-high value for the initial current minimum, iterate the list, and each time you find a value less than the current minimum, update the current minimum value. After you've exhausted all the values, the "current minimum" will be the minimum of all the values. Finding a maximum is the same, but you'd start with an impossibly-low value so the first "real" value is guaranteed to be higher than that. How might that be implemented?

Comment: How do i get it tho? I'm trying with forEach, is that right?

`public void olderPerson(String nomeAgenda){
        int i = 99999;
        if (nomeAgenda.equals("Amigos")) {
            Familia.forEach(contato -> {
               int c = contato.getIdade();
                if(c < i) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            });
        }
    }`

Comment: getIdade() is the method that gets age from Contato or Contact.

Comment: I provided an answer using streams, but I now see you flagged your question with `for-loop`. If you want the stream answer let me know and I'll restore my answer.

Comment: Side note: one does not compare `String` objects with `==`. So the `if (nomeAgenga == "Amigos")` is not going to work. Use `if ("Amigos".equals(nomeAgenda)` so that the `.equals` method is used. The example code has a mix of `==` and `.equals()` in it.

Comment: @Ozzott Normally `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` are picked to represent an "impossibly-low" or "impossibly-high" value respectively.

Comment: Further: you should adhere to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are written in camelCase, that means they start with lowercase, e.g. `Amigos` should be `amigos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return oldest person in one list:

```
public Contato oldestPerson(String nomeAgenda){
    return Familia.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getNome().equals(nomeAgenda)) // contatos named nomeAgenda
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Contato::getIdade)) // take oldest
            .get();
}
```

For all lists you can do:

```
public Contato oldestPerson(){
    return Stream.of(Familia,  Amigos, Profissional)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream) // flatting to one long stream
            .filter(c -> c.getNome().equals(nomeAgenda)) // contatos named nomeAgenda
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Contato::getIdade))
            .get();
}
```

### EDIT

Based on the comment, we should change a couple of things to achieve what you want. First, we should define a `Map<String, List<Contato>>` and populate it in the constructor:

```
private Map<String, List<Contato>> contatoGroups;
private static final String familiaKey = "Familia";
private static final String amogisKey = "Amigos";
private static final String profissionalKey = "Profissional";

public GestaoContatos(Contato c) {
    super(c.nome, c.idade, c.sexo, c.profissao, c.telefone, c.email);

    contatoGroups.put(familiaKey, new ArrayList<>());
    contatoGroups.put(amogisKey, new ArrayList<>());
    contatoGroups.put(profissionalKey, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

(Consider using `enum` instead of `String` as key in the map)

Then wherever you want to get a group, for example: `Familia`, you should do:

```
List<Contato> contatoes = contatoGroups.get(familiaKey);
```

And then we should change the `oldestPerson()` like this:

```
public Contato oldestPerson(String nomeAgenda){ // nomeAgenda could be "Familia", "Amigos"...
    List<Contato> selectedGroup = contatoGroups.get(nomeAgenda); 

    return selectedGroup.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Contato::getIdade)) // take oldest
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! But this method receive what parameter? nomeAgenda in the context means the name of the arraylist(Amigos, Familia or Profissional) where the method will search the oldest person.

Comment: @Ozzott I have edited my answer now based on your comment.